# Dimension of the $\mathbb K$ vector space over the $\mathbb K$ field.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am unable to find justifications for saying the dimension of the $\mathbb K$ vector space.

I know that every $\mathbb K$ field can be considered a vector space over itself, but how dimension this space be? Something tells me it's $1$, but I can't justify it consistently. Can someone help me?

Comment: What definition are you using for dimension? That's a good place to start.

Comment: Is this: "The common cardinality of any base of $V$ is called the dimension of
$V$." Where $V$ is $\mathbb K$ vector space.

Comment: Can you find a basis for $\mathbb K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\dim_{\mathbb{K}}V$  denote the dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. We will prove that $\dim_{\mathbb{K}}\mathbb{K}= 1$ by finding a basis for $\mathbb{K}$ over the field $\mathbb{K}$ with one element.

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{1\}$ where $1 \in \mathbb{K}$ is the multiplicative identity of the field $\mathbb{K}$ (we could choose any other non-zero element of $\mathbb{K}$, but $1$ makes the proof a little simpler). First, note if $a \cdot 1 = 0$ then $a = 0$. Therefore, $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent. Next, we show that any $b \in \mathbb{K}$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$. Indeed, $b = b \cdot 1$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis and $\dim_{\mathbb{K}}\mathbb{K}= 1$.

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of a $k$-vector space is the cardinality of any basis. For finite dimensional vector spaces, we also write this as an integer. So all you have to do is note that $\{1\}$ is a basis for $k$ over itself. (Note that $\{x\}$ is also a basis for any $0\neq x\in k$.)